# Android: cannot resolve symbol getDefaultProguardFile

Tags: android, gradle, proguard, android-proguard

I have a problem with gradle. It can't find `getDefaultProguardFile()` method.

Here is how it looks like:

[image]

None of these is working:

- clean project
- rebuild
- invalidate caches and restart

**Does someone know what is the problem?** I am working on the last version(1.5) of Android Studio.

Comment: I have been seeing this lately too, looks like an [open issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=69731).

Comment: @cziemba I am looking for an answer from a long time and I decided to post a question in case someone found the problem. I see now that they said ``It does not affect any functionality. You don't need any workarounds.`` But a solution is still welcome.

Answer (score 0):

[reference google issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=69731)
Just update your **buildTypes** instead your .

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

Then **Clean - Rebuild** And 
**File -> Invalidate Cache / Restart** . I hope it will helps you .

Comment: Why would you delete ``minifyEnabled false``?